# discard changes not staged for commit

Tags: git, github

When I `git status` under my project I see:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   MyApp/mylib (new commits)
```

The `mylib` is a git submodule under which there are other files.

I would like to discard changes in `MyApp/mylib`. So, I tried run command:

`git restore MyApp/mylib`

But after that when I `git status` again, I see the same result. How can I discard changes of `MyApp/mylib` so that it doesn't show as changes not staged?

Comment: Is `mylib` a submodule?

Comment: yes it is a submodule, I will update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `modified (new commits)` status really just means that the submodule is currently "on" a different commit than the superproject calls for.

To force the submodule back to the commit that the superproject calls for, you need to have Git itself run:

```
git -C MyApp/mylib switch --detach $hash
```

where `$hash` is the hash ID that the superproject (i.e., your current commit in *your* repository) is calling for.  Where do you get that hash ID?  Well, the easy way is to let Git fish it out for you, by running:

```
git submodule update --checkout MyApp/mylib
```

The `git submodule` command has a lot of modes; the `update --checkout` mode says *using the current superproject commit, find the `$hash` value, and then run the above `git -C` command to check out that commit within the submodule*.

(The fact that the submodule *is* on the "wrong" commit is suggestive though: it means that maybe you *don't* want to force the submodule back to the superproject's recorded commit.  Maybe instead you'd like the superproject to record the *submodule's current commit*.  But you did not ask how to do that, so let's not confuse things more.)

Answer (score 0):

Either of these 2 should work:

- To discard unstaged changes to a file permanently:

  `git checkout -- MyApp/mylib`
- To discard changes and save them for later use

  `git stash`

Comment: That only works for files, not for submodules.